# mysql_connect() always denies access

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp, mysql-connect

I have phpMyAdmin running with MAMP, and I am finding it impossible to use mysql_connect().

```
$_db_connect = mysql_connect("root", "localhost");
```

Produces an error in php_error.log:  `mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Access denied for user` `'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /....../common.lib.php on line 19`

I've checked out the privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

and I am simply stumped.  I've created new users with passwords just to get the same result.  Strangely it always says (`using password: NO`), even when I attempt to connect as a user witha password:

```
$_db_connect = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
```

Any advice is welcomed.  Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php   third param should be password

Comment: your root has password. `mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');`

Comment: Try the password "root" see also my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the password in the function. Also, the function call is wrong. Do it like this:

```
$_db_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
```

where, `password` is the password for your root account. It might be different.

Comment: I have tried this, as I say in my original post.  Also, my root account has no password.

Comment: But the error statement states: `'*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B'` as your root password(obviously encrypted).

Answer (score 4):

That error message for dummies:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It has three parts, each of it contains important information. Let's see:

1. *Access denied* - In plain words, this means: Get lost! Don't try to connect to me.
2. *for user 'root'@'localhost'* - That says who is denied access, that user. The name: **root** and at (@) the following server: **localhost**.
3. *using password: NO* - Just some nice additional information that when trying to access and giving the user-name, no password was used.

So now on with the privileges you have:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
 IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B'
 WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

It basically says, that the user `'root'@'localhost'` needs to use a password to get access. As the error message tells you, you are not using a password. So that is likely to be the cause of the error, the password is missing.

Add the password and try again.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to enter the passwort. If I guess right then is the hash `81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B` the password "root" (to confirm enter this SQL statment: `SELECT PASSWORD('root')`.

Try to login with the correct password:

```
$_db_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the password, as the third parameter

```
$_db_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

first param in mysql_connect function is db host and you need to use 3 params - to use password.

so use this syntax:

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');